# Why current_user is NoneType in forms.py? (Wtforms, Flask, flask_login current_user)

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, flask-login

So I want to have a form where I can insert a song. But I want to extract albums from a
query, and in order to start the query I need to specify the user that I get from current_user. But When I execute I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/profscrew/Desktop/Progetto_Basi_Dati-master/Codice/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .artist.routes import artist
  File "/home/profscrew/Desktop/Progetto_Basi_Dati-master/Codice/artist/routes.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Codice.artist.forms import *
  File "/home/profscrew/Desktop/Progetto_Basi_Dati-master/Codice/artist/forms.py", line 28, in <module>
    class SongForm(FlaskForm):
  File "/home/profscrew/Desktop/Progetto_Basi_Dati-master/Codice/artist/forms.py", line 41, in SongForm
    album = SelectField("Album", choices=Album.get_albums(current_user.username), validate_choice=True )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Here is forms.py:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import  StringField, PasswordField,DateField,SubmitField,SelectField,EmailField
from flask_login import current_user
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, Optional

from Codice.models import *
from Codice.database import *
from Codice.artist.forms import *

class SongForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Name", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=40)])
    cover = StringField("Cover", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=120)])
    content=StringField("Content", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(max=120)])
    release_date=DateField("Release Date", validators=[DataRequired()])
    genre=SelectField("Genre", choices=Genre.list)
    album = SelectField("Album", choices=Album.get_albums(current_user.username), validate_choice=True )
    
    premium = SelectField("Premium", choices=[' ','The song will be premium','The song will be available to everyone'],
                          validate_choice=True )
    
    submit = SubmitField("Upload")
```

Here is routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user

from Codice.models import *
from Codice.database import *
from Codice.artist.forms import *

# Blueprint Configuration
artist = Blueprint('artist', __name__, static_folder='static',
                 template_folder='templates')


@artist.route('/insertsong', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def insertsong():
    form = SongForm()
    return render_template('insertsong.html', form = form, user = current_user)
```

Here is the query in models.py:

```
class Album(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'albums'                   # obbligatorio

    idalbum = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    cover = Column(String)
    artist = Column(String, ForeignKey(Artist.username))

    artists = relationship(Artist, backref=backref(
        "albums", cascade="all,  delete, delete-orphan"))

    def get_albums(temp_username):
        albums = Session_artist.query(Album).filter(Album.artist == temp_username).all()
        return albums
```

Can anyone explain why forms.py has current_user as NoneType? And if there is any method to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: `current_user` isn't set until you call `login_user()`. You didn't do that before defining the `SongForm` class.

Comment: login_user() was called in another folder when i do the authentication. Do I have to do it again?

Comment: You don't have to do it again, but you have to ensure that it happens before you define the class.

Comment: you use `current_user.username`  in class `SongForm` but its fields are created when you start program and this value doesn't exits yet. And you can't run `login_user()` before Python create `SongForm` - you would have to send `current_user.username`  to `SongForm` as parameter - like `form = SongForm(current_user.username)` - but this needs to add some code in `SongForm` to get this value and create field `album`

Comment: @furas so i need to make my own __init__(username) and call super inside?

Comment: yes, it may need to use `__init__(username)` and `super().__init__()`. But I didn't find any example which would show how to create field in `__init__()`